# How to wait for an asynchronous process to complete inside a for loop before incrementing the loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await

I need to iterate through an array. With each iteration, I need to update my database. I need to wait for the first update to be complete and then make the second update.
After searching through several answers, I found ASYNC/AWAIT feature of ES2017. However, I have not been able to implement it so far. The updates are happening randomly and not in a sequence. Please let me know how to implement ASYNC/AWAIT in this situation
Here is my code snippet:

```
function findRecipe(product, qty) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Recipe.findOne({
            product: product
        }, (err, recipe) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                for (let i = 0; i < recipe.items.length; i++) {

                    Item.findOne({
                        name: recipe.items[i].name
                    }, (err, item) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err)
                        } else {
                            var lessAmt = recipe.quantities[i] * qty;
                            item.stock -= lessAmt;
                            item.save((err, item) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err)
                                } else {
                                    resolve(item)
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    });
}

for (let i = 0; i < bill.product.length; i++) {
    //Calling function for updates for each item
    findRecipe(bill.product[i], bill.qty[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are nearly there, Just Wrap the loop in a function and make it async.

```
async function updateAllRecipe(){
 for(let i=0;i<bill.product.length;i++){
 //Calling function for updates for each item
 await findRecipe(bill.product[i],bill.qty[i])
 }
}
```

But seriously though, I think you can leverage of parallelism here using the Promise.All. Is it really necessary to wait for the recipe to finish before queing the next findRecipe method? If not use the promise.all for it to perform faster

Comment: AwesomeI it works.Thanks!  Also I was not returning the promise from my function. I am getting consistent DB results now. Yes I need to do the updates sequentially because the updates are happening to the same database. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, as long as it helps you :D

Answer (score 0):

Async Await is easy to implement once you know the basic concept of asynchronous nature of Nodejs, I have used `for...of` loop here which also works asynchronously.

```
//Async function to perform database updates

async function findRecipe(product, qty) {
try {
    let recipe = await Recipe.findOne({ product: product });
    let i = 0;
    for (itemObj of recipe.items) {
        let item = await Item.findOne({ name: itemObj.name });
        var lessAmt = recipe.quantities[i] * qty;
        item.stock -= lessAmt;
        let updatedItem = await item.save();
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}
catch (err) {
    return err;
 }
}



async function someasyncFunction() {

    for (let i = 0; i < bill.product.length; i++) {
        //Calling function for updates for each item
        await findRecipe(bill.product[i], bill.qty[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh..This has made my code concise and readable. Really cleared the concept for me.

Comment: No problem buddy, happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use Promise.all and start process parallel. It'll increase the performance of API.

```
  async function findRecipe(product, qty) {
        try {
            let recipe = await Recipe.findOne({
                product: product
            });
            const items = await Promise.all(recipe.items.map(itemObj => Item.findOne({
                name: itemObj.name
            })));

            const items = await Promise.all(items.map((item, i) => {
                var lessAmt = recipe.quantities[i] * qty;
                item.stock -= lessAmt;
                return item.save();
            }));
            return true;
        } catch (err) {
            return err;
        }
    }



    async function someasyncFunction() {
        await Prmise.all(bill.product.map((product, i) => findRecipe(product, bill.qty[i])));
    }
```